# NQueens Slver in python

Tags: python, backtracking

I am making a nQueen Problem Solver but every time I run the program it launch this error:

"tuple" has no attribute "row"

I want to know if the function place is well structure because is the one that throw the error

```
import sys #use of argv

#Create the object queen with the row and column
class Queen:
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Row: "+ str(self.row) + " Column: " + str(self.col)

#Validate if I can place the Queen in that space, return false or true
def place(Board,row,col):
    for i in range(0,len(Board)-1):
        #Attack conditions: cant place in the same column, row and diagonal
        if (Board[i].row == row) or (Board[i].col == col) or (abs(Board[i].row - row) == abs(Board[i].col - col)):
            return False
    return True

#Recursive function that Append the queen to the board if it can be place
def NQueens(Board,n,row):
    for i in range(1,n):
        #if the row is > than n the fuction will return the list 
        if (row > n):
            return Board 
        #If it can be place we call the NQueens function with the next row
        elif place(Board,row,i):
            Queenaux = (row,i)
            Board.append(Queenaux)
            NQueens(Board,n,row+1)

#The user enter the number of queens and size of the board
n = int(sys.argv[1])
print("nQueens Problem Solver")
print("Chess Board: ",n,"x",n)
print("Number Queens:",n)
#Create the list Board
Board = []
#Start the NQueens function with row=1
Board = NQueens(Board,n,1)
#Print the queens in the board and their coordinates
print (Board)
```

Comment: What's the `Queens` variable?

Comment: Sorry dude, Queens = Board, I already change it but it didnt work the same error appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Queenaux = (row,i)
Board.append(Queenaux)
```

Because of these lines, `Board` contains tuples. You must fix it by making `Queenaux` a `Queen` instance, like so:

```
Queenaux = Queen(row,i)
```

Also note that `NQueens` doesn't return anything so you shouldn't assign it to `Board`. Just call the function and let it do the modifications.

Comment: `NQueens` sometimes returns something. It is inconsistent. This is one of several structural problems. While the fix above solves the original error, it doesn't make the algorithm correct. There are many problems here. Have you read about Rohl's 2 algorithm?